# RxAndroidBle: If client is in observable state how to perform Read and Write operations?

Tags: rx-java, rxandroidble

While establishing connection i used `.asObservable()` property to stay connected.

```
bleDevice = rxBleDevice;
rxBleDevice.establishConnection(false)
        .flatMap(RxBleConnection::discoverServices)
        **.asObservable()**
        .subscribe(rxBleDeviceServices -> swapScanResult(rxBleDeviceServices));
```

After connection established when i tried to read values it show

> Already connected to device

```
 bleDevice.establishConnection(false)
        .flatMap(rxBleConnection -> Observable.combineLatest(
                    rxBleConnection.readCharacteristic(gattCharacteristicList.get(6).getUuid()),
                    rxBleConnection.readCharacteristic(gattCharacteristicList.get(7).getUuid()),
                    ReadValuesOnConnection::new
        ))
        .subscribe(
                readValuesOnConnection -> Log.i("UUid 6 Value: ", readValuesOnConnection.value_1+""),
                throwable -> Log.e("Error", throwable.getMessage())
        );
```

Logs:

```
I/Bluetooth Enable: True
I/RxBle#QueueOperation: Scan operation is requested to start.
I/Scan Results:: 6Q:6C:05:8E:F5:5B
I/Scan Results:: 6P:6A:05:8E:F8:2X
I/RxBle#CancellableSubscription: Scan operation is requested to stop.
W/zygote64: Suspending all threads took: 5.645ms
I/Characteristics List size:: 33
E/Error: Already connected to device with MAC address 6Q:6C:05:8E:F5:5B
```

I go through the sample project but didn't find any solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you mean by `client is in observable state`? `.asObservable()` is not a property but a function that—in this particular case—changes nothing as the result of `.flatMap()` is already an `Observable`.

`Already connected to device with MAC address` comes from `BleAlreadyConnectedException` and is indication that one tries to establish a new connection when there is one already opened.

What you probably want is to combine the two independent flows into one that would do both: `swapScanResult` and read characteristics. You could do this like:

```
subscription = rxBleDevice.establishConnection(false) // first we want to establish the connection
  .flatMap( // once the connection is established
    RxBleConnection::discoverServices, // we want to explicitly discover the services
    (rxBleConnection, rxBleDeviceServices) -> { // when both the connection and services are available
      swapScanResult(rxBleDeviceServices); // we swap scan result?
      return Observable.combineLatest( // and start reading characteristics
        rxBleConnection.readCharacteristic(gattCharacteristicList.get(6).getUuid(),
        rxBleConnection.readCharacteristic(gattCharacteristicList.get(7).getUuid(),
        ReadValuesOnConnection::new // when both characteristics are read we combine the result
      );
    }
  )
  .flatMap(observable -> observable) // we need to flatMap the result as we returned an Observable from the first flatMap
  .take(1) // after the read has completed we unsubscribe from the upstream to make the connection close
  .subscribe( // we consume the result
    readValuesOnConnection -> Log.i("UUid 6 Value: ", readValuesOnConnection.value_1+""),
    throwable -> Log.e("Error", throwable.getMessage())
  );
```

Additionally this flow uses some side effects which make it potentially non-deterministic. You call a method `swapScanResult(RxBleDeviceServices)` and in other place you use `gattCharacteristicList.get(int).getUuid()` and feed it back to the flow.

It is possible to make the code more easy to follow by doing a change to the above mentioned method and access to the list of characteristics (that is stored as a property). It is as simple as changing it into a pure function that could have a signature like:

```
static Pair<UUID, UUID> getUuidsOfCharacteristicsToRead(RxBleDeviceServices services);
```

Comment: I'd like to read some value from peripheral after every 3 seconds, Any thoughts?

Comment: Should be fairly easy.

Comment: Could you please provide any examples or tutorial? Because I tried to connect first time - **It connected properly** and then I tried to write characteristic, But it is showing `Already connected to device with MAC address` error.

Comment: There are already some examples and questions on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rxandroidble). You can browse them or ask a new question.

Comment: With rxandroidble 1.11.1 this no longer compiles - `RxBleConnection::discoverServices` gives `Bad return type in method reference: cannot convert io.reactivex.Single<com.polidea.rxandroidble2.RxBleDeviceServices> to io.reactivex.ObservableSource<?>`. Is that an RxJava2 issue?

Comment: Yes, `RxAndroidBle` based on RxJava2 has a different API (some `Observable` become `Single`, some `Completable`). General idea is the same but one needs to use `.flatMapSingle()`/`.flatMapCompletable()`, `Single.zip()`... etc. where appropriate.